# Where does PyQT look for resource files?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm using QT Designer to create UI forms which include bitmap images. The images are stored as resource files, and processed by pyrcc4 into files like `img_rc.py`. The forms are compiled at runtime by `loadUiType()`. The question is where do I put the resource files? The documentation says to put them in the folder with the `.ui` files, but if I do that I get

`ImportError: No module named img_rc`

On the other hand, if I put `image_rc.py` in the current working directory from which I start the python script then it loads correctly. In fact, I can remove the `.py` file and leave only the bytecode file `image_rc.pyc` in the working directory and it still works.

The ui forms are intended to be used as a package across many different applications. Keeping resource files in the working directory rather than within the package doesn't make any sense. The `from_import` argument claims to affect how imports are resolved, but I haven't been able to make it do anything but return `ValueError: Empty module name`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the documentation state that you put the generated py files in the UI directory?

I've always put them in the current working directory - directory where your main python file is located - and it always worked fine for me.

Comment: Although I am unfamiliar with pyrcc4, I would assume that the folder you keep the generated resource files needs to be on the Python path just like with any other module you want to import. This would explain why it works when placed in the program directory.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem / come up with a solution? I am currently facing the same situation.

Comment: Old question but here is a tip. Compile the ui file using `pyuic4` or  `pyuic5` and open the generated .py file, or alternatively in QtDesigner go to `Form > View Python Code...` Here, you will see the import statement. Mine looks like `import icons_rc` which indicates it is looking for the import in the same directory as the compiled ui file.